# xcode - TableView rows from bottom to top

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

For my little project, I need you help.
I already created a functioning table view. Now I want that the rows goes from bottom to top and not like usually from top to bottom. How do I do that?

Comment: What do you mean exactly? In what way will your table view be different? What's wrong with a normal table view? Just scroll it to the bottom and add rows to the top.

Answer (score 9):

First you rotate your UITableView 180 degrees upside down, and then rotate your individual cells also upside down.

Take a look: [UITableView anchor rows to bottom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5679835/uitableview-anchor-rows-to-bottom)

Comment: Why? There's no reason for this. A normal table will work just fine.

Comment: Yes, a "normal" table is all you need, but if you want the cells to start at the bottom and "grow" up instead of the default top->bottom, then you need this small hack. I assume that is what you are interested in @rmaddy?

Comment: I'm saying there is no need to transform the tableview. Just add rows to the top instead of the bottom. Until the OP clarifies their goal, I see no reason to suggest flipping the tableview and its cells.

Comment: "Now I want that the rows goes from bottom to top and not like usually from top to bottom." - that's OP's goal. To do that you have to transform the tableview.. I don't understand what "Just add rows to the top instead of the bottom." means?

Comment: What does "rows goes from bottom to top" mean? That's what the OP needs to clarify.

Comment: hmm I don't see how it's not clarified? Normally the rows in a tableview goes from the top to the bottom - OP wants it from the bottom to the top :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you can target iOS 6+, this answer suggests using UICollectionView to lay out rows in reverse order: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23895000/144088.

Answer (score 0):

The most simple solution,
 you can use `array.reversed()` to show the last object of the array at the top of tableview