# UITableView Scroll to Top

Tags: swift, uitableview

I have created a Table which contain Chat. i just transfromed tableview by using

```
chatTable.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1, y: -1)
```

I need to Make these cards(in screenshot below) to show on top when user open a chat for first time.
[image]

i tried this peice of code

```
chatTable.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: -chatTable.contentInset.top), animated: true)
```

it doesn't worked!

How to acheive that layout? need suggestions.

Comment: your data response also that type.

and also need to transform call 

yourCell.contentView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1, y: -1)

Comment: Dont use transform, instead adjest top inset of your scrollView

Comment: Why should not use Transform @SPatel. what are disadvantages?

Comment: 1. it will not work with RTL.
2. Hard to understand.

Comment: @SagarBhut yes, i wrote same for cells too.Actually the screenshot i have posted contains cells rotated. cells will populated from bottom to top.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23715555/configure-uicollectionviewflowlayout-to-layout-rows-from-bottom-to-top?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this issue by adding condition 
if messages count is more than zero, transform table. if not, Table remains normal.

```
    if messages.count == 0 {
      //show some views
    } else {
      //Transform table along with cells.
      //show Messages
    }
```